# Libgdx ImageButton padding?

Tags: java, libgdx, imagebutton

so I have this problem with ImageButton class of libgdx, the problem is that in android the image doesnt expand to the full size of the button, and in desktop it does or at least it does more, so I have to ask if theres a way to force the image to get the size of the background(button)? so i can try to make an equal visualitation on both plataforms.

heres a screen shot, the back space button is the ImageButton...
[image]

edit: heres the code....

```
    private void createButtons() {

        ImageButtonStyle ibs = new ImageButtonStyle(buttonD,buttonD_p,buttonD,bsIcon,bsIcon,bsIcon);
        buttonBS        = new ImageButton(ibs); // This is the backspace button

        ....
    }
    private void addButtonsToTable() {
        float pad = 1;
        float BUTTON_SIZE = this.BUTTON_SIZE - pad *3;
        table.top();
        table.center();
        table.add(buttonBS).width(BUTTON_SIZE).height(BUTTON_SIZE).pad(pad);
        table.row();

        ...
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your exact GUI-building code? The buttons should be exactly the same on both platforms. Are you using a `Table` to display the buttons?

Comment: yes Im using a table. and sure, when i get home ill post the code

Comment: Just posted the code, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the image to be the *background* instead of just an icon, you should consider using plain `Button` or `TextButton` instead of `ImageButton`. `ImageButton` should be used only for buttons that draw an icon *additionally* to its background. An example of `ImageButton` usage could be the window closing button with the "X" (cross) image, or music toggle button with a loudspeaker icon.

When you need the image to fill the whole button area, set it as `ButtonStyle#up` - it will become button's background. `ImageButton#imageUp` is just an icon that will not be scaled in any way (by default), so that might be the reason why your application behaves differently on each platform.

(Although it still shouldn't, unless you use different assets.)

If you need an icon and still want to use `ImageButton`, consider that internally it is just a `Button` with an `Image` instance added to one of its cells (`Button` is a `Table`). You can use `ImageButton#getImageCell()` to access `Cell` in which the `Image` is stored and modify it - for example, force a specific width and height. You might also want to use `ImageButton#getImage()` to change scaling with `Image#setScaling(Scaling)`.

Anyway, creating styles at runtime can be error-prone - the style constructor is huge and I'm honestly unable to guess which drawable draws what without checking out image button style sources. You should consider using [`Skin`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Skin) and define your styles with JSON files (you can find some free themes [here](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-skins)).

Comment: I understand, but I need the background and the icon, thats why im using ImageButton. I really dont need the desktop application, what i fear is that in some android devices, it might behave like in my desktop application, I also dont what it to fill the whole area, i want it to behave the same in all android devices so i can be sure no devices is displaying it like my desktop application. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Then what is the point of using an icon, if you want it to fill the whole image? `ImageButton` internally is just a `Button` with an `Image` instance added to one of its cells (`Button` is a `Table`). You can use `ImageButton#getImageCell()` to access `Cell` in which the `Image` is stored and modify it - for example, force a specific width and height. You might also want to use `ImageButton#getImage()` to change scaling with `Image#setScaling(Scaling)`.

Comment: Like I said, I dont want the icon to fill the background, just to behave the same. BUT it will be easier if it fill the whole background, ill just add a transparent padding to my image and done. and it cant be just a button because, the user can change the background color and the numbers colors(in this case the icon color) so I can do that easily with buttonBS.getImage().setColor(color); and buttonBS.setColor(color);

Comment: I see. Well, you can go with `buttonBS.getImageCell().size(whatever)` to force a specific size of the icon on each platform. I'd make sure that the scaling is correct, though - you might want to use `buttonBS.getImage().setScaling(x)` as well (just replace `x` with a `Scaling` that fits your needs, like `Scaling.fill`).

Comment: so, this did the trick `buttonBS.getImageCell().size(BUTTON_SIZE);`  thanks! but why use the scaling?

Comment: The scaling allows you to change how the image fills the button. If it is set to `Scaling.none`, icon probably wouldn't fill it at all. I was afraid that somehow the `Image` in `ImageButton` defaults to this mode, but fortunately it doesn't. Anyway, you can use scaling to decide whether the icon should keep its aspect ratio when you modify its size, so that can be still useful.